lmdb.InvalidParameterError: /data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/WDC/wdc.db: Invalid argument
I am working on hypersigma github below. Please refer to the link below. By the way I have a problem.

HyperSIGMA github Link: https://github.com/WHU-Sigma/HyperSIGMA

The input is a dc.tif file downloaded from the site below, and I created two mat files (train_0.mat, train_1.mat) using the create_WDC_dataset function of 'mat_data.py'. Then we tried to convert the two mat files (train_0.mat, train_1.mat) to the wdc.db file.
I tried to create the data.mdb, lock.mdb, meta_info.txt files in the wdc.db folder through the createDCmall function of lmdb_data.py, but the meta_info.txt file was not created. Below is the related error.

https://engineering.purdue.edu/~biehl/MultiSpec/hyperspectral.html
Washington DC Mall Image (145MB) --------> (dc.tif)

====================Command Result Start======================
(venv) techwinjeo@gpusystem:~/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility$ python lmdb_data.py 

create wdc...
(1587, 191, 8, 8)
map size (GB): 0.17344493865966795
/data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/WDC/wdc6.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/lmdb_data.py", line 95, in <module>
createDCmall()
File "/data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/lmdb_data.py", line 85, in createDCmall
create_lmdb_train(
File "/data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/lmdb_data.py", line 55, in create_lmdb_train
env = lmdb.open(name+'.db', map_size=map_size, writemap=True)
lmdb.InvalidParameterError:        /data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/WDC/wdc.db: Invalid argument

====================Command Result End======================
Any help is highly appreciated 
Thank U :D
I'm looking forward to creating the following three files in the file path below.

path: /data/project/hsi_foundation/HyperSIGMA/ImageDenoising/utility/WDC/wdc

wdc.db
|
|----- data.mdb
|----- lock.mdb
└----- meta_info.txt

